# get a variable inside and/or outside a tuple using sed or perl

Tags: linux, perl, shell, sed

input file:

```
{custom:{ver:120,name:hello,form:123},name:world,browser:ie}
{custom:{ver:130,name:test,form:123},browser:ie}
```

sed command:

```
sed 's/^.*name:\([^,]*\).*$/\1/' input.txt
```

output :

```
world
test
```

How do I differentiate the variable inside the tuple and that outside the tuple?

Expected output for the value of `name` inside `custom`:

sed command inside custom name

```
hello
test
```

sed command outside custom name:

```
world
blank or {custom:{ver:130,name:test,form:123},browser:ie}
```

NOTE: `name` can appear anywhere in the file--beginning, middle or end--or can be absent.

perl would also work for me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name inside the custom using a rather unsophisticated regex:

```
perl -lne 'print /custom:\{[^{}]*name:([^,}]*)/ ? $1 : ""' input.txt
```

Outputs:

```
hello
test
```

Name outside the custom:

```
perl -lne 'print /custom:\{[^{}]*\}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|name:([^,}]*)/ ? $1 : ""' input.txt
```

Outputs:

```
world
```

**Switches**:

- `-l`: Enable line ending processing
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){...}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

Comment: They work good when line have name , when there is no name in the line it just deletes the line . In the 2nd command output there should be blank line in 2nd line as there is no name in input

Comment: Then use a conditional operator instead of an if.

Answer (score 2):

It's much simpler to read and maintain if you treat it as JSON.

```
use JSON qw( decode_json );
while (<>) {
   s/(\w+)/"$1"/g;
   my $data = decode_json($_);
   print($data->{name}, "\n") if $data->{name};
}
```

As a one-liner:

```
#Any version
perl -MJSON -nle'
   s/(\w+)/"$1"/g;
   my $data = decode_json($_);
   print $data->{name} if $data->{name};
'

#5.10+
perl -MJSON -nE'
   s/(\w+)/"$1"/g;
   my $data = decode_json($_);
   say $data->{name} if $data->{name};
'

#5.14+
perl -MJSON -nE'
   my $data = decode_json( s/(\w+)/"$1"/gr );
   say $data->{name} if $data->{name};
'

#5.14+
perl -MJSON -nE'say for grep $_, decode_json( s/(\w+)/"$1"/gr )->{name}'
```

Comment: Thanks this also worked buy very slow , it looks i need install json::XS module to speed up parsing . it took 1 hour to parse 55 columns in 25 mb file.

Comment: I went for reliability and flexibility without spending much on development time. Yes, it doesn't have the speed of a hackish solution. Yes, installing JSON::XS will greatly speed it up if you don't have it installed already.

Comment: with installing JSON::XS module , will the performance be equivalent to hakish solution ?  ( with the hakish solution , that 25mb file was parsed in a minute or two ) . If the performance is almost equal i need recommend my company to have that installed . Thanks !!